# VSCODE ON Monterey not working with Golang

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I get the following error on vscode on Monterey with golang
Tools environment: GOPATH=/Users/randolphhill/devgo/workspace, GOBIN=/Users/randolphhill/devgo/workspace/bin
Installing 1 tool at the configured GOBIN: /Users/randolphhill/devgo/workspace/bin in module mode.
dlv

Installing github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@latest FAILED
{
"killed": false,
"code": 2,
"signal": null,
"cmd": "/usr/local/opt/go/libexec/bin/go install -v github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@latest",
"stdout": "",
"stderr": "go: cannot find GOROOT directory: /usr/local/opt/libexec\n"
}

1 tools failed to install.

dlv: failed to install dlv(github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@latest): Error: Command failed: /usr/local/opt/go/libexec/bin/go install -v github.com/go-delve/delve/cmd/dlv@latest
go: cannot find GOROOT directory: /usr/local/opt/libexec

Answer (score 0):

That seems like an odd GOROOT path. Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling Go?

I have go installed and it is located at `/usr/local/go/bin/go` not `/usr/local/opt/go/libexec/bin/go`.

From the Go website: https://go.dev/doc/manage-install; The default install location is usually /usr/local/go.